# How to Visualize a 3D Graph From R?

Tags: r, 3d

I recently made a 3D graph using R that anecdotally does exactly what I wanted it to do -- and looks about as I'd expect.

However, when I try to look up specific data points to see if I can identify the ID attached to the plot -- I can't do it. Can someone please help let me know if I'm looking at this 3D graph incorrectly (since I admittedly haven't dealt with them since college), or if I might have ran the code wrong?

Here's a screenshot of the graph with lines I drew of where I'd expect point (x=35, y=61, z=90) to be:

[image]

My assumption was that the three points would intersect and I would find ID# 3605.

They get very close to intersecting in some places, but I don't know if my lines are off, I'm thinking about it wrong, or if I might have plotted it incorrectly.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It's almost impossible to locate a point in the projection with a fixed perspective. Using RGL is not much more difficult, and you can interactively rotate the image; this helps in point identification. Anyway, nobody can tell you if you did something wrong because you posted no code.

Comment: @DieterMenne   Yup, thanks. I feel 99% certain that my code is fine -- I just thought that if there was an easier way to locate a point that I was missing and that point wasn't there, that could've meant it was wrong. But if it's just almost impossible to locate a point with a fixed perspective, that essentially answers the question. Thanks!